# Using CSS/HTML to build background?

Tags: html, css, web, html5boilerplate

Guys I have been trying lots of different options from cutting up to building in html/css. nothing seems to really work :(

How would you guys go about doing this ?

Link:- http://www.flickr.com/photos/gavinwynne/6902590869/

Comment: You mean you want a background image to stretch across 100% of the page? Then [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) may help; otherwise you'll need to explain more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a thick border and a inset box shadow.  Browser support is somewhat limited, though.  It basically comes down to IE9+ and modern browsers ([ref](http://trentwalton.com/2010/11/22/css-box-shadowinset/)).

### [demo](http://jsbin.com/icugen/2/edit#preview)

```
body {
    min-height: 300px;
    border: 24px solid #666;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    padding: 35px;
}
```

[image: demo screen shot]

Comment: use PIE css for IE7+ if *really necessary*

Comment: Thansk, this was an option but I would really like to keep the torn paper effect

Answer (score 2):

One of the most common ways about doing it would be to cut the image in 3 pieces as shown in the below picture:

[image]

Where piece 1 would be shown first, then make piece 2 height equal to 1px and repeat it on the y axis through CSS and then put piece 3 at the bottom in order to "close" the container

Your html could be in the form of:

```
<div class="div_top"></div>

<div class="div_middle"> your content here </div>

<div class="div_bottom"></div>
```

### Update

Css would be something similar to this :

```
 .div_top { 
      background-image:url('top_bg.jpg');
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      width:800px;
  }

 .div_middle { 
      background-image:url('middle_bg.jpg');
      background-repeat:repeat-y;
      width:800px;
  }

 .div_bottom { 
      background-image:url('bottom_bg.jpg');
      background-repeat:no-repeat; 
      width:800px;
  }
```

You'd probably want to set a fixed height for your top and bottom divs, since they have no content and wont actually expand to show the background image.

Comment: Also the repeat 1 px is going to leave out alot of the torn effect for the left and right. Anyway to show more of this effect ?

Comment: @GavinWynne - Just cut out a bigger chunk of the middle part of the paper and use that as background instead. But make sure that it tiles seamlessly first as it'll look ugly if it doesnt

Comment: Amazing thanks. Could I take a bigger middle_bg so that I get more of the texture ? or is this not user friendly.

Comment: oh ok, just saw your post. Is this bad practise what I am doing ? should I be going down the border route >

Comment: Its not a bad practice and you shouldn't have any problems either way. You could take for example 20px, and repeat those accordingly but take good care between the start and end of the repeated texture so you don't have a visible "choppy" point between them. The reasoning behind repeating the texture is to keep the image size as small as possible but with internet speeds nowayday there shouldn't be any great difference between a couple of kilobytes

Comment: Thanks for your help with this, much appreciated. Oh and to the others who responded :) - i will click all for useful posts :)

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer is sufficient, please accept the answer so others can find it easily in the future.